# Search for a string in a command output with multiple lines using batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a command that returns multiple lines. Inside the output, I want to search if a file name is present. I am able to get the output stored in a variable. But the `findstr` is not working properly on the variable
This is the batch script I am using:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


REM The two empty lines are required here
set "output="
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('p4 describe -s 66518131') do (
    if defined output set "output=!output!!LF!"
    set "output=!output!%%f"
)

set "file=filename"

echo %!output!% | findstr /C:"%file%" 1>nul

if errorlevel 1 (
  echo. got one - pattern not found
) ELSE (
  echo. got zero - found pattern
)
```

But I am always getting `errorlevel` as 1, even when the filename is present in the command output. What am I doing wrong here?
Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why is `%!output!%` not `%output%` or `!output!`?

Comment: Change `echo %!output!% | findstr /C:"%file%" 1>nul` to `cmd /D /V /C echo(^!output^!| findstr /C:"!file!" 1>nul`, which transfers expansion to the `cmd` instance initiated for the left side of the pipe, which is necessary for the line-feeds to survive…

Comment: Simpler: `p4 describe -s 66518131 > output.txt` followed by `findstr /C:"%file%" output.txt`. Simplest: `p4 describe -s 66518131 | findstr /C:"%file%"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a small mistake in the `findstr` line. As the comment to the question suggests, changing `%!output!%` to `%output%` fixed this issue